# Removing whitespace from string

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm trying to figure out how to properly code this. I have to read a file which has 3 variables within it, separated by spaces:

```
  Planet      Diameter (miles)  Length of Day (hours)
Mercury          3032             4222.6
Venus            7521             2802.0
Earth            7926               24.0
Jupiter         88846                9.9
```

In my code I am supposed to parse the line into 3 variables (planet, diameter, length), echo this data, and then convert the diameter and length. My problem is that I do not know how to properly assign the variables diameter and length so that there is no whitespace stored in them, which would then allow me to use stod to then perform the calculations (I think).

```
int main()
{
    //Declare Variables
    string line;
    string planet;
    string diameter;
    string length;

    //Application Header
    cout << "Welcome to Planet Poachers" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

    //Open file
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("PlanetsIn.txt");

    // Open the file and check that it was found and correctly opened
    if (!dataIn)
    {
        cout << "Error finding and opening the data input file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //Read past header
    getline(dataIn, line);

    //Echo data
    while (dataIn.good())
    {
        //getline(dataIn, line);
        cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
        getline(dataIn, line);

        //Assign variables
        planet = line.substr(0, 10);
        diameter = stod(line.substr(11, 21));
        length = stod(line.substr(22, 40));

        //Display data
        cout << "Input line (miles, hours): ";
        cout << planet << diameter << length << endl;
        cout << "Output line (kilometers, days): ";
        cout << planet << (diameter * 1.609344) << (length / 24)
            << endl << endl;

    }

    //Close file
    dataIn.close();

    //End of application
    cout << endl << endl << "End of Application. Press Any Key to Exit.";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `double` for `diameter` and `length`?

Comment: You've defined `diameter` as string. How would you expect a string to be multiplied or divided? Clearly you need a number for that, if you use a little common sense. (Unless you expect `"Tyler" * 123.45` to be a valid calculation?)

Comment: You can use `cin >> length` to read variables in, just like you can use `cout << length` to print them out.

Comment: @DanielH you forgot to mention the good news that `cin >>` automatically skips whitespace.

Comment: @Tyler *I dont know how to read the file into the variable* -- Write a small `main` program and practice how to do this *before* you write your larger program.  No more than a two line `main` program could have been used to practice on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your variables planet, diameter and length are all std::string. You cannot perform arithmetic on strings. You can parse the various fields into your string variables, but then you would need to convert those strings into doubles. i.e.

```
double dia_dbl = std::stod(diameter);
double len_dbl = std::stod(length);

std::cout << planet << ": " << (dia_dbl * 1.609) << "," << (len_dbl / 24) << std::endl;
```

std::stod discards any leading whitespace.

Comment: The question explicly mentions `stod`, so they're obviouly already aware of it.

Comment: I was aware of the stod command, but I didnt know that it already removed whitespace as during my lab I was told that this command existed, but not much beyond that. With your code I was able to figure it out. I think my problem was that when I was doing the stod(diameter), I did not try to assign that conversion to a new double variable and was trying to assign the converted number into the same string variable again. A bit of a brainfart on my part.